# DataTable com RowExpansion Editable não da Update - PrimeFaces

Tags: java, primefaces, datatable

Tenho uma `DataTable` que expande a linha em uma `DataTable` editável, na expansão é possível adicionar itens, pelo botão "+ Item", está funcionando tudo correto, mas não consigo atualizar a tabela, fazendo com que assim que adicionado um item, o mesmo já esteja disponível para edição dentro do `RowExpansion`.
Da maneira que está o usuário tem que clicar a quantidade de vezes que quer em "+ Item", salvar, recarregar e ai os itens aparecem para ser editados.
 Outro probleminha que tem é que uma das colunas da expansão é um `SelectOneMenu`, e ele não está visível, apenas quando eu clico na célula para editar é que ele aparece.

Bean

```
@SuppressWarnings("serial")
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ProcessamentoBean implements Serializable{

    private OrdemDeServico selectedODS;
    private Item item;
    private List<Produto> produtos;
    private List<OrdemDeServico> listaODS;
    private List<Item> listaItens;


    public OrdemDeServico getSelectedODS() {
        return selectedODS;
    }
    public void setSelectedODS(OrdemDeServico selectedODS) {
        this.selectedODS = selectedODS;
    }
    public Item getItem() {
        return item;
    }
    public void setItem(Item item) {
        this.item = item;
    }
    public List<Produto> getProdutos() {
        return produtos;
    }
    public void setProdutos(List<Produto> produtos) {
        this.produtos = produtos;
    }
    public List<OrdemDeServico> getListaODS() {
        return listaODS;
    }
    public void setListaODS(List<OrdemDeServico> listaODS) {
        this.listaODS = listaODS;
    }
    public List<Item> getListaItens() {
        return listaItens;
    }
    public void setListaItens(List<Item> listaItens) {
        this.listaItens = listaItens;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void listar(){
        try {
            OrdemDeServicoDAO odsDAO = new OrdemDeServicoDAO();
            listaODS = odsDAO.buscarProcessamneto();

        }catch (RuntimeException erro){
            Messages.addGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao listar as Ordens de Serviço");
            erro.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void onRowToggle(ToggleEvent event) {

        selectedODS = (OrdemDeServico) event.getData();
        listaItens = new ArrayList<Item>();

        ItemDAO itemDAO = new ItemDAO();
        listaItens = itemDAO.buscarPorODS(selectedODS.getCodigo());        

        ProdutoDAO produtoDAO = new ProdutoDAO();
        produtos = produtoDAO.buscarPorODS(selectedODS.getCliente());              
    }

    public void maisItem() {
        try{
            item = new Item();
            item.setOdsID(selectedODS);
            item.setItemNum(listaItens.size()+1);
            item.setMultiplicador(1);
            item.setProdutoID(produtos.get(0));
            if (item.getProdutoID().getImpresso()){
                item.setImpresso('N');
            } else{
                item.setImpresso('-');              
            }
            if (item.getProdutoID().getEnvelopado()){
                item.setEnvelopado('N');
            } else{
                item.setEnvelopado('-');                
            }
            if (item.getProdutoID().getGrampeado()){
                item.setGrampeado('N');;
            } else{
                item.setGrampeado('-');             
            }       

            listaItens.add(item);           
        }catch (RuntimeException erro){
            Messages.addGlobalError("Selecione uma ordem de serviço.");
            erro.printStackTrace();
        }           
    }   

    public void menosItem() {
        try{    
            listaItens.remove(listaItens.lastIndexOf(item));            
        }catch (RuntimeException erro){
            Messages.addGlobalError("Não há itens para serem removidos.");
            erro.printStackTrace();
        }
    }       

    public void itemSalvar() {
        try{
            ItemDAO itemDAO = new ItemDAO();

            for (Item i:listaItens){
                itemDAO.merge(i);               
            }

            listaItens = new ArrayList<Item>();

            Messages.addGlobalInfo("Itens salvos com sucesso!");
        }catch (RuntimeException erro){
            Messages.addGlobalError("Ocorreu um erro ao salvar os itens.");
            erro.printStackTrace();
        }
    }   
}
```

xHtml

```
<ui:define name="conteudo">
    <h:form id="formODS">
        <p:growl id="msgs" showDetail="true" />
        <p:dataTable id="tabela" emptyMessage="Não há nada para ser processado."
            value="#{processamentoBean.listaODS}" var="ods" 
            rowKey="#{ods.codigo}" rowExpandMode="single" widgetVar="processamento">

            <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{processamentoBean.onRowToggle}" update="formODS:tabela"/>

            <f:facet name="header">
                <p:commandButton value="+ Item" actionListener="#{processamentoBean.maisItem()}"
                    update=":mensagem formODS:tabela:expanded"/>

                <p:commandButton value="- Item" actionListener="#{processamentoBean.menosItem}"
                    update=":mensagem :formODS:tabela">
                </p:commandButton>

                <p:commandButton value="Salvar" actionListener="#{processamentoBean.itemSalvar}"
                update=":mensagem :formODS:tabela">
                </p:commandButton>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column width="2">
                <p:rowToggler/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="OS Nº" width="10" style="text-align:center">
                <h:outputText value="#{ods.codigo}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Entrada" width="15" style="text-align:center">
                <h:outputText value="#{ods.dataEntradaFormatada}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Cliente" width="30" style="text-align:center">
                <h:outputText value="#{ods.cliente.nomeInterno}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Produto" width="20" style="text-align:center">
                <h:outputText value="#{ods.produto}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Quantidade" width="20" style="text-align:center">
                <h:outputText value="#{ods.quantidadeFormatada}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Multiplicador" width="20" style="text-align:center">
                <h:outputText value="" />
            </p:column>             

            <p:column headerText="Observações" width="100">
                <h:outputText value="#{ods.observacao}" />
            </p:column>

            <p:rowExpansion>
                <p:dataTable id="expanded" emptyMessage="Clique em + Item para adicionar itens" editable="true" editMode="cell" 
                    value="#{processamentoBean.listaItens}" var="item" styleClass="processamentoExpanded" >

                    <p:column width="30" style="text-align:center">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.itemFormatado}" />
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Produto" width="20" style="text-align:center">
                       <p:cellEditor>
                           <f:facet name="output">
                                <h:outputText value="#{processamentoBean.item.produtoID.nomeProduto}"
                                converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter" />
                           </f:facet>
                           <f:facet name="input">   
                                <h:selectOneMenu value="#{processamentoBean.item.produtoID.nomeProduto}" 
                                converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                                   <f:selectItems value="#{processamentoBean.produtos}" var="produto" 
                                   itemLabel="#{produto.nomeProduto}" itemValue="#{produto}" />
                               </h:selectOneMenu>
                           </f:facet>
                       </p:cellEditor>              
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column width="20" style="text-align:center">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"> <h:outputText value="#{item.quantidade}" /> </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"> <p:inputText value="#{item.quantidade}" style="width:30%" /> </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column width="20" style="text-align:center">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"> <h:outputText value="#{item.multiplicador}" /> </f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"> <p:inputText value="#{item.multiplicador}" style="width:30%" /> </f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>              
            </p:rowExpansion>
        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>

    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
            rowExpansion(PF('processamento'));
         });

         function rowExpansion(dataTable) {
               var $this = dataTable;
               $this.tbody.children('tr').css('cursor', 'pointer')
               $this.tbody.off('dblclick.datatable-expansion', '> tr')
                  .on('dblclick.datatable-expansion', '> tr', null, function() {
                     $this.collapseAllRows();
                     $this.toggleExpansion($(this).find('div.ui-row-toggler'));
                   });
        }
    </script>   

</ui:define>
```

Alguém consegue me ajudar??

Comment: Tente atualizar a tabela de Expansion no botão salvar..
<p:commandButton value="Salvar" actionListener="#{processamentoBean.itemSalvar}"  update=":mensagem :formODS:tabela formODS:tabela:expanded" />

Comment: Primeiramente, obrigado pela atenção. Então, coloquei isso lá e o salvar continua funcionando da mesma forma, eu adiciono x itens e eles não são listados na hora, quando eu clico salvar ele salva os itens novos do banco de dados e atualiza a tabela colapsando a linha que estava expandida. Expando ela novamente e os itens agora estão lá para editar normalmente. Mas a ideia era o "+ Item" e o "- Item" serem dinâmicos, que o cara possa botar o que precisa, editar e salvar já pronto no DB.

Answer (score 1):

Problemas resolvidos. Deixarei a solução caso alguém venha ter a mesma dúvida.

Para atualizar a dataTable dentro de um rowExpansion dentro de outro dataTable fiz o seguinte:
Botões:

```
    <f:facet name="header"> 
        <p:commandButton value="+ Item" actionListener="#{processamentoBean.maisItem}" oncomplete="rc()"/>
        <p:commandButton value="- Item" actionListener="#{processamentoBean.menosItem}" oncomplete="rc()"/>
        <p:commandButton value="Salvar" actionListener="#{processamentoBean.itemSalvar}" update="formODS"/>     
    </f:facet>
```

E dentro do rowExpansion coloquei o seguinte:

```
<p:remoteCommand name="rc" update="expanded"/>
```

Quanto ao problema do selectOneMenu o código que funcionou desta forma:

```
<p:column width="20" style="text-align:center">
    <h:selectOneMenu id="produtoMenu" value="#{item.produtoID}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
        <f:selectItems value="#{processamentoBean.produtos}" var="produto" itemLabel="#{produto.nomeProduto}" itemValue="#{produto}" />
    </h:selectOneMenu>      
</p:column>
```

Comment: Funcionou!!! Mas, e onde está a função javascript que é chamada em cada botão? Visto que o remoteCommand chama uma função js..